# Can't deliver emails to microsoft

Tags: postfix, spam, email

I have a postfix server, on Ubuntu 13.04.
On my domain, I set up correctly every MX, SFP, DKIM and A record.

I've tested them with gmail, reports DKIM and SPF PASSED. So no problems, my mails comes in Inbox with every mail service. Except one. Microsoft.

Microsoft keeps cut my emails off. They can't even reach Spam folder. Now, what should I do to reach Microsoft without forcing my users to add the domain to whitelist?

Test that I've done:

SPF:

http://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester

http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

http://www.appmaildev.com/it/spf/

MX, and other stuff:

http://mxtoolbox.com/

DKIM:

GMail

http://www.appmaildev.com/it/dkim/

All of them passed.

Comment: anything in postfix logs?

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html - debug the SMTP connection and see what is really happening...or post those logs if you already have them.  You can also remove the successful header info to GMAIL, it isn't necessary and makes the question long.

Comment: 1. Microsoft is not an ISP. 2. Neither is Google. 3. If your problem is sending email to a Microsoft email address then why did you post the headers from an email to a GMail email address? 4. Do you get an NDR when sending email to a Microsoft email address?

Comment: @dusan.bajic Nope, nothing, it acts just as an ordinary mail.

Comment: @TheCleaner I will try and edit the question when I have logs.

Comment: @joeqwerty 1 & 2 mistype, sorry. 3 The full mail from gmail it stands like a proof i have correct values. 4 pardon my noobish, what's a NDR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending mail using `HELO mail.edennetwork.it` and that domain resolves to the correct IP address.

However the reverse DNS (PTR record) for the IP address does not resolve back to the same domain.  It resolves to `static.193.150.4.46.clients.your-server.de`.

You should contact your hosting provider and request that they change the PTR record for that IP address to `mail.edennetwork.it`.  If they won't do that, you should change your `HELO` to match the `PTR` record (or change your hosting provider).

You might also want to check that your IP is not on [SpamHaus's PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/) and [read through this](https://serverfault.com/questions/368663/hotmail-wants-me-to-modify-my-spf-record).

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I really didn't care about PTR...